# OpenSSL pass the password to a tcl file

Tags: encryption, openssl

My requirement is to encrypt/decrypt a tcl file without a OpenSSL password prompt, but read the password automatically from a file. My test_en.tcl  has the following encrypt/decrypt commands:

```
exec openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in  test_en.tcl -out encrpt_test_en.tcl
exec openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in encrpt_test_en.tcl > new_test_en.tcl
```

How can I read the password from a file into tcl script and avoid manual entry to encrypt/decrypt the file automatically?

Please suggest correct way to send the password to tcl script.

Answer (score 0):

From `man openssl` , you can see that `enc`  have the option `-kfile` .

```
   -kfile file
             Read the password to derive the key from the first line of file.  Superseded by the -pass option.
```